# tidyr::pivot_longer coming up with :Error: Can't combine `TSPAN6` <character> and `MT-CO2` <double>

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Im trying to use the pivot_longer function to convert a long row of gene IDs into a longer column.
I'm using the following code:

```
file1 <- file1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -Gene.ID, names_to = "tissue", values_to = "counts")
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't combine `TSPAN6` <character> and `MT-CO2` <double>.
```

I think I need to set the default for the columns to be characters but I'm unsure how to do so without also affecting the values within the column. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Turn the column to character and then get data in long format. `file1 %>%mutate(\`MT-CO2\` = as.character(\`MT-CO2\`)) %>%tidyr::pivot_longer(......)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think there are multiple columns in this data that have the same issue and could take a while to edit them all. Is there any way of changing the whole row of gene names to a default of character?

Comment: To turn all the columns to characters try `file1 %>%mutate_all(as.character) %>%tidyr::pivot_longer(......)`

Comment: That took too long to work so I think its doing the whole file

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I'm trying to make a table but the file is massive and I'm struggling to get it into a readable format

Comment: If you know how to share a file I could do that?

Comment: Provide example data: `dput(head(mydata))`

Comment: My rows are about 10,000 in length so head would just freeze my laptop

Comment: Then can you at least show `str(mydata)`?

Comment: ..   AC018529.3 = col_character(),
  ..   AL049776.1 = col_character(),
  ..   Z82170.1 = col_character(),
  ..   AC105114.1 = col_character(),
  ..   AP000542.2 = col_character(),
  ..   AL513497.1 = col_character(),
  ..   AC135584.1 = col_character(),
  ..   AC135068.4 = col_character(),
  ..   AC005915.1 = col_character(),
  ..   AL118508.4 = col_character(),
  ..   ENSG00000279448 = col_character(),
  ..   AC006277.1 = col_character(),
  ..   Z99129.4 = col_character(),
  ..   AP003499.3 = col_character()

Comment: That is part of my string but it goes on for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with:

```
file1[, ] <- sapply(file1[, ], as.character)
```